# What happened to Jeremy Aster?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, klingon, worf

So in the TNG Season 3 episode "The Bonding", Worf and Jeremy Aster perform the R'uustai, a ritual that binds them together as brothers, effectively joining Jeremy Aster to the House of Mogh.

What happened to Jeremy Aster after that? Are there any books or follow-up stories about this character?

Comment: House of Mogh*. The House of Moog(ie) is Ferengi.

Comment: his daughter went back in time to become the first female mp in the british parliament?

Comment: @ Omegacron - Haha! You're right, of course!  There is a hydraulic actuator company in Europe called Moog, but it is pronounced like Mogh, so I usually mess that up.

Answer (score 6):

Per the [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Jeremy_Aster) article on Jeremy Aster;

> As an adult, Aster pursued a career in archaeology, and by 2375 was
>   working toward his doctorate at the Rector Institute. That year, he
>   was also involved in a romantic relationship with a woman called
>   Marra. By the end of that year, however, their relationship had ended.
>   (TNG novel: [Diplomatic Implausibility](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Diplomatic_Implausibility))
>
> Jeremy would later assist Worf and Alexander Rozhenko in the Genesis
>   Sector, helping to keep the Moss Creatures from unleashing a new
>   Genesis Wave on the galaxy. During this time, Jeremy joined the House
>   of Martok. (TNG novel: [Genesis Force](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Genesis_Force))
>
> Aster also became close with Worf's adoptive parents, Sergey and
>   Helena Rozhenko, and regularly dined at their home. (TNG novel:
>   Diplomatic Implausibility)

He also appeared briefly in the DC Comic "[The Lesson](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lesson)"

[image]

Comment: He appears in several fan-made films as well; http://stexpanded.wikia.com/wiki/Jeremy_Aster

Comment: It would be worth noting that this is all EU, and not canon (querent is asking for books, but unlike other sci-fi properties, books are not canon - if they were thinking that)

Comment: Books are not canon, that's true, but I was just wondering if they ever did anything more with the character.  It would have made great sense to me if Alexander and Jeremy ended up growing up together like Worf and Nicholai, only this time, the human acts more Klingon and the Klingon acts more human.